# Crashlytics - <redacted> entries in crash reports

Tags: ios, crashlytics, tvos

We are seeing a problem in most of the crashes detected. We are seeing lines with redacted text specifically for UIKit and other system libraries, making us difficult to understand the crash. We are uploading the dSYM files to Crashlytics, enabling bitcode and sharing the symbols with iTunesConnect.
Example:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKit                          0x1934eb4b4 <redacted> + 460
1  UIKit                          0x193457f74 <redacted> + 296
2  UIKit                          0x19344e110 <redacted> + 384
3  UIKit                          0x193336818 <redacted> + 132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189e74dfc <redacted> + 32
5  CoreFoundation                 0x189e72724 <redacted> + 412
```

Also, is there a way we can download the .crash file instead of the current crash report in .txt format? The crash file help us to symbolicate manually but the .txt files does not have the Binary Images section.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What OS and version are you seeing that on?

Comment: Hey @MikeBonnell, we are seeing it in Apple TV, with tvOS 12.

Comment: Also includes tvOS 11.

Comment: Can you update to the latest version of the SDK 3.10.9 and let me know if that helps?

Comment: @MikeBonnell we've seen this issue persistently between all the versions of Crashlytics. We are updating it to latest version to validate your answer, but do you know why is this happening? Why it's saying **redacted**?

Comment: There are numerous reasons why redacted can show up. If you use Bitcode and don't share symbols with Apple, then the dSYM won't have the symbols. If you use a 3rd party library that doesn't share the symbols, or if the configuration of your app is such that Dwarf with dSYM isn't included and thus symbols aren't generated.

Comment: @MikeBonnell But the redacted symbols are coming from UIKit, what dSYM files are needed for UIKit? Or does that mean it could be a 3rd party framework that handles UIKit objects?

Comment: That's another potential option. I am also double checking that we have the symbols from Apple on these two tvOS versions, that could be another cause. Symbols are complicated :)

Comment: @MikeBonnell Can you let me know as soon as you can if you are handling the symbols from Apple for those tvOS versions please? Just want to start narrowing down the potencial causes.

Comment: Crash reports on tvOS 12 and 11 should look better now for new issues.

Comment: @MikeBonnell thanks. We are gonna look at next release and check the issues.

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell, just wanna let you know that UIKit and UIKitCore issues has been fixed in the new release. But now we are seeing redacted symbols for CoreFoundation and Foundation for tvOS 11. Can you check if those are already up too? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update, double-checking.

Comment: Hey @MikeBonnell, We are seeing again redacted symbols for tvOS 12.1, can you check if those symbols are uploaded please? We'd much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a link to the crash?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Is there a way I can send it to you directly? I'm not allowed to share it publicly.

Comment: Please email support(at)fabric(dot)io and reference this thread.